# saving detached objects using spring data jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, eclipselink

I'm trying to fetch a list of entities from database, make changes then insert them as new rows(not update). I've managed to do this by autowiring EntityManager and detaching the objects one by one(perhaps a bulk detach would be nicer). but when I add a @OneToMany relation to my entity and try to persist I get this:

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-07-17 11:42:32.584--ClientSession(1851088021)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'code' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO branch (id, provinceId) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="branches" sql="INSERT INTO branch (id, provinceId) VALUES (?, ?)")
2016-07-17 11:42:32.627 ERROR 2172 --- [nio-9099-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'code' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO branch (id, provinceId) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="branches" sql="INSERT INTO branch (id, provinceId) VALUES (?, ?)")] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'code' doesn't have a default value
```

but this doesn't make sense since Branch has many more fields/columns:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private Long code;
@NotBlank
private String title;
@NotNull
private Long provinceId;
@NotBlank
private String grade;
private Long versionId;
```

this is the definition of branches in my province entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(name = "branch",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "provinceId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
)
private List<Branch> branches;
```

this is the code where I try to insert the rows:

```
    final List<Province> provinces = provinceRepository.findByVersionId(copyFromVersionId);
    for(Province province : provinces){
        entityManager.detach(province);
        province.setId(null);
        province.setVersionId(id);
        for(Branch branch : province.getBranches()){
            entityManager.detach(branch);
            branch.setId(null);
            branch.setVersionId(id);
        }
    }
    provinceRepository.save(provinces);
```

how can I save the new branch rows as copies of my query result? what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you retrieve an object, that object has an id and represents an object in the datastore. You cannot then "re-persist" it with some new id, since it already has an "id". Create a new object yourself. Basic JPA API and object lifecycles

Comment: as far as I know you can't "re-persist" it unless you first detach the object using entity manager, which works for my Province object but not for the OneToMany relation inside it.

Comment: that is not "re-persist". That is "merge" ... under the same "id".

Comment: @NeilStockton actually I'm saving my province objects with null "id"s and it is auto incremented which is my desired behavior

Comment: As already said, you CANNOT CHANGE THE ID OF AN OBJECT.

Comment: @NeilStockton I don't understand you man. I'm telling you I did change the ID of my entity objects to null and it worked(I can upload a sample if you like). if you mean that you can't change the ID to anything but null; well that is not my question since I want to change the ID to null so that it is auto incremented.

Comment: Neil is stating that such behavior is unsupported by the JPA specification and may lead you to various issues unless you know all the specifics of how your provider handles everything under the covers under all situations that you might use now and in the future.  Change tracking for instance, might cause the provider to associate changes to the existing entity rather than a new one - or as in this case, doesn't see any changes to the 'new' entity .  EclipseLink has copy tools you would be better off using such as http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#CopyGroup

Comment: @Chris thanks man, this seems like a neat way to deal with my problem, though I couldn't get it to also copy the branches(it copies the reference), would you care to make an answer; and perhaps also clarify why detach shouldn't be used here and where it should be used. if not I will answer the question myself.